# Percentage difference of the last value from the previous values of a column based on certain data group within the same table

Tags: t-sql

I have a table shown in below image. Actually i want to calculate the percentage difference in this table. The methodology of calculating the difference will be as following.

1-Records are logically grouped by Column2.

2-We want to compare value of column3 with the other records of the group but the column3 value is taken based on the max-value of column 1 in the group.

[image: Table Image]

Comment: The values in the last group should be -23.076 and -33.333, right?

Comment: Yes, You are right. The should be negative.

Comment: For future questions, prefer to post code and samples in text, not images. You can also use [dbfiddle.uk](http://dbfiddle.uk) to help others. Also edit the question and add the DBMS (I suppose it's SQL Server) and version you use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your version of SQL Server is recent enough (2012+), the problem can be solved with the window/analytic function [`LAST_VALUE()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql):

```
Column4 = (LAST_VALUE(Column3) OVER (PARTITION BY Column2 ORDER BY Column1) 
           - Column3) / Column3 * 100
```

or `FIRST_VAUE()` with inverse order:

```
Column4 = (FIRST_VALUE(Column3) OVER (PARTITION BY Column2 ORDER BY Column1 DESC) 
           - Column3) / Column3 * 100
```